# How does combat power work?

Tags: galaxy-attack-alien-shooter

When you click upgrade you see combat power in the bottom of the screen.
When you upgrade your spaceships this number goes up.

What does combat power actually mean?
Does it make the attack of all your spaceships stronger?

If so is it significant.
I avoided buying multiple spaceships because i have a maxed out legendary spaceship and I want to maximize my chance of having that powerup drop rather then some weaker spaceship

but I dont know if I am loosing out on actual damage output???

This is the game btw:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alien.shooter.galaxy.attack&hl=en_US

Comment: Do you guys know if they have an official website i could ask this question? I would then post the answer here. Im sure there will be people confused about this in the future as well.

Comment: This game seems to have little to no information anywhere online other than YouTube and I find this very very bizarre. As for the power, it just makes your ship's attack stronger. I've maxed out the 2nd ship and have an alternate skin and the power increase is noticeable.